# Add dictionary for Aspell

Tags: php, apache, spell-checking, aspell

I want to use the PSpell Class which is a provided extension on my apache server.
Unfortunately when I use the function pspell_new("de"), following warning message will be displayed:

> Warning: pspell_new(): PSPELL couldn't open the dictionary. reason: No
>   wordlists can be found for the language "de". in
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/jeddsan.ch/httpdocs/assistent/spellchecker.php on
>   line 6

I now found a service, which provides the dictionarys for german.
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html

Now I downloaded the bz2 file, extracted it and now I don't know, what I now have to do?

[image: That are the files, which I can see and I don't know what to do with them.]

Which files are important and where must I place the files?

Thanks for every response.

Comment: I also ran into same problem, I figured out to install a dictionary file we need to follow the instructions given in the README file from the unzipped folder. I posted a detail answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177768/no-pspell-link-found-opened